# How to stop the vibration of my application when leaving the activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In this activity I use vibration, so it is up to the user to choose the ball that moves to the rhythm of the vibration, but when I want to return to a screen backwards, that is, to `MainActivity`, the app continues the vibration without stopping it. This is my code, I already tried everything and I can't fix it.

I have tried closing it from the `MainActivity` by making an object of type Vibration and nothing, just the vibration continues. In fact if I don't close the app completely, it could keep browsing on my device and the vibration on the device would follow. I wish they could help me to solve such a conflict. The `onDestroy()` is just testing that I was doing, but it doesn't work, I would like to have another suggestion to solve this problem.

```
public class RitmoUno1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button buttonBolaRoja;
Button buttonBolaAmarilla;
Button buttonBolaAzul;
Button buttonSalir;

//Vibrator
Vibrator vibrator;

//Bola modelo uno
ImageView imageBolaModeloUno;
AnimationDrawable bolaModeloUnoRitmo;

//Bola modelo dos
ImageView imageBolaModeloDos;
AnimationDrawable bolaModeloDosRitmo;

//Bola modelo tres
ImageView imageBolaModeloTres;
AnimationDrawable bolaModeloTresRitmo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ritmo_uno1);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Vibraciones");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    buttonBolaRoja= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_bola_roja);
    buttonBolaAmarilla= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_bola_amarilla);
    buttonBolaAzul= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_bola_azul);
    buttonSalir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ritmo_salir);

    //Animación de bola roja
    imageBolaModeloUno = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_bola_ritmo_uno);
    imageBolaModeloUno.setImageResource(R.drawable.bola_ritmo_uno);
    bolaModeloUnoRitmo = (AnimationDrawable) imageBolaModeloUno.getDrawable();
    bolaModeloUnoRitmo.start();

    //Animación de bola amarilla
    imageBolaModeloDos = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_bola_ritmo_dos);
    imageBolaModeloDos.setImageResource(R.drawable.bola_ritmo_dos);
    bolaModeloDosRitmo = (AnimationDrawable) imageBolaModeloDos.getDrawable();
    bolaModeloDosRitmo.start();

    //Animación de bola azul
    imageBolaModeloTres = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_bola_ritmo_tres);
    imageBolaModeloTres.setImageResource(R.drawable.bola_ritmo_tres);
    bolaModeloTresRitmo = (AnimationDrawable) imageBolaModeloTres.getDrawable();
    bolaModeloTresRitmo.start();

    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    //La unidad de medida de las vibraciones son los milisegundos
    //1000 milisegundos equivalen a 1 segundo
    //Duerme por 200 milisegundos y vibra por 500 milisegundos
    final long [] pattern = {200, 500};
    vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);

    buttonBolaRoja.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openSiguientePantalla();
        }
    });

    buttonBolaAmarilla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    buttonBolaAzul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

}

public void openSiguientePantalla(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RitmoUno2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

//No funciona esto, sólo son pruebas que hice
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cancel the vibration in onDestroy

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    vibrator.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the phone.
I.e. if the phone is allowing vibrations or if it isn't, try selecting the mute all vibrations on your phone as well

Comment: Check the setting for details